# MediaPlayer will not stop or pause

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to make a simple app to help me learn how to code for Android. The apps principle is simply this: When you press down on a button it starts  playing a sound file. When you release the button, the audio stops. Pressing down on the button works, but releasing it does not. Thanks in advance! Here is my java code:

```
package com.example.siriu.presstoplay;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.util.Log;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.pressbutton);
    button.setOnTouchListener(handleTouch);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);

}


private View.OnTouchListener handleTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.d("button", "down");
                    play();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.d("button", "up");
                pause();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
};

public void play (){
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);
    mp.start();
    Log.d("MediaPlayer", "started");
}

public void pause (){
    mp.stop();
    Log.d("MediaPlayer", "paused");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Android MediaPlayer will not stop or pause

Because in your `play ()` method you are starting local declared `MediaPlayer` of `play ()`  method
and in your `pause ()` you are trying to stop `MediaPlayer` that you have declared global

> in this situation  your global declared  `MediaPlayer mp;` hasn't start yet

**Try this**

Remove `final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);` from Your `play()` Method

```
public void play (){

    mp.start();
    Log.d("MediaPlayer", "started");
}
```